# Capture the return value from nursery objects

Tags: python-3.x, python-trio

When using trio and `nursery` objects, how do you capture any value that was returned from a method?

Take [this](http://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-core.html#errors-in-multiple-child-tasks) example from the trio website:

```
async def append_fruits():
    fruits = []
    fruits.append("Apple")
    fruits.append("Orange")
    return fruits

async def numbers():
    numbers = []
    numbers.append(1)
    numbers.append(2)
    return numbers

async def parent():
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        nursery.start_soon(append_fruits)
        nursery.start_soon(numbers)
```

I modified it so that each method returns a `list`. How would you capture the return value so that I could print them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently, there is no built-in mechanism for this. Mostly because we haven't figured out how we would even want it to work, so if you have some suggestions that would be helpful :-).

The thing is, with regular functions, there's exactly one obvious place to access the return value – the caller is waiting, so you hand them the return value, done. With concurrent functions, the caller isn't waiting, so you also need some way to specify where to return it to, when to return it, if there are multiple functions you have to keep track of which one is returning a value, and so on. It's not as simple a concept.

What do you want to do with the return values? Do you want to, say, print them immediately when each function returns? In that case the simplest thing is to do it directly from the tasks:

```
async def print_fruits():
    print(await fruits())

async def print_numbers():
    print(await numbers())

async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
    nursery.start_soon(print_fruits)
    nursery.start_soon(print_numbers)
```

You could even factor this into a helper function:

```
async def call_then_print(fn):
    print(await fn())

async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
    nursery.start_soon(call_then_print, fruits)
    nursery.start_soon(call_then_print, numbers)
```

Or maybe you want to put them in a data structure to look at later?

```
results = {}

async def store_fruits_in_results_dict():
    results["fruits"] = await fruits()

async def store_numbers_in_results_dict():
    results["numbers"] = await numbers()

async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
    nursery.start_soon(store_fruits_in_results_dict)
    nursery.start_soon(store_numbers_in_results_dict)

# This is after the nursery block, so we know that the dict is fully filled in:
print(results["fruits"])
print(results["numbers"])
```

You can imagine fancier versions of those too – for example, sometimes when you run a lot of tasks in parallel you want to capture exceptions, not just return values, so that some tasks can still succeed even if some of them fail. For that you can use a `try`/`except` around each individual function, or the [`outcome`](https://outcome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) library. Or when each operation finishes you could put its return value into a [`trio.Queue`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-core.html#passing-messages-with-queue), so that another task can process the results as they're finished. But hopefully this gives you a good starting point :-)

Comment: Any ETA yet on when you will have figured this out? How you want it to work I mean? Because having a simple future that'd be guaranteed to be filled after the nursery block as a return value of a modified `start_soon()` would be completely sufficient for a start and a huge boon to the functionality of trio.

Comment: +1, some kind of simple `trio.Future` object would be very useful here. I guess essentially what `outcome.Outcome` is.

Comment: Is there an open issue about this, by any chance? I think i would expect each call of `start_soon` to return a future... By the way, it looks to me that nurseries are just nested event loops with extra guaranties.

Comment: I've been modifying class instances in the trio start_soon functions so I don't have to keep the start_soon function in the same file

Answer (score 1):

In this case, simply create the arrays in the parent and pass each to the child that needs it.

More generally, pass an object to the tasks; they can set an attribute on it. You might also add an `Event` so that the parent can wait for the results to be available.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [`ResultCapture` class in aioresult](https://aioresult.readthedocs.io/en/stable/result_capture.html). (Disclaimer: I wrote that library.) That way, you can just return a value directly from your coroutines as in the examples in your question.

```py
async def parent():
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        fruits = ResultCapture.start_soon(nursery, get_fruits)
        numbers = ResultCapture.start_soon(nursery, get_numbers)
    print("fruits:", fruits.result())
    print("numbers:", numbers.result())
```

It's possible to wait for an individual result with `ResultCapture.wait_done()` which, I must admit, is normally a bad habit – it's usually better to wait for an enclosing nursery to finish as in the snippet above. But I think the general principle of returning a value is good practice (rather than passing in a mutable "return" value as an argument).